# Fail to use enum properly with ngSwitch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, enums

I have three buttons that shows three different lists, so I wanted to add `enum`s to help me decide which list to present using `ngSwitch`, but I'm getting an error.

This is the TypeScript:

```
export enum ListType {People, Cars}

export class AppCmp implements OnInit {

    listOfPeople: Person[];
    listOfCars: Car[];

    currentListView: CurrentListView;

    constructor(private _MyService: MyService) {
    };


    public setListType(type: ListType) {
        this.listType = type;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this._MyService.getListOfPeopleData().subscribe(res => {
        this.listOfPeople = res;
      });

      this._MyService.getListOfCarsData().subscribe(res => {
        this.listOfCars = res;
      });
    }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div>
  <button md-button
          (click)="setListType(listType.People)"
          class="md-primary">People
  </button>

  <button md-button
          (click)="setListType(listType.Cars)"
          class="md-primary">Cars
  </button>
</div>


<md-content>

  <h1 align="center">{{title}}</h1>

  <div [ngSwitch]="currentListView">

    <div *ngSwitchCase="listType.People">
        <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#person of listOfPeople">
          ID: {{person.id}} <p></p> name:{{person.name}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="listType.Cars">
        <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#car of listOfCars;>
          ID: {{car.id}} <p></p> color: {{car.color}}
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</md-content>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

The error is:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors: Can't
bind to 'ngSwitchCase' since it isn't a known native property ("  
  <div [ngSwitch]="currentListView">

     <div [ERROR ->]*ngSwitchCase="listType.People"> Property binding ngSwitchCase not used
by any directive on an embedded template ("  
  <div [ngSwitch]="currentListView">
```

I'm using Typescript and Angular2.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @JCorcuera added the error, sorry

Comment: Shouldn't it be `export enum ListType {People, Cars}` ?

Comment: it is, I changed it, it didnt work...

Comment: `*ngFor="#car of listOfCars;>` there's a `"` missing at the end of this. It should be ...`*ngFor="#car of listOfCars;">`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Considering the `enum`:

```
export enum ListType {People, Cars}
```

If you want to use it in the template, like:

```
...
<div *ngSwitchCase="listType.People">
...
```

You have to [make the enum available to your component](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2885) by creating a property in your class that will act as an "alias" (in that template) for the `enum`, like this:

```
export class AppCmp implements OnInit {

  public listType = ListType;  // <-- a prop with the name you want to use for the enum
...
```